# chrome debug log value different from actual value inside variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, console

I am passing one variable with string value to function xyz which is failing, but when i am copying same variable values from browser console and passing directly to same xyz function, it started working.

Not getting what browser console changing in values which works for me after logging in console.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: function description is require where it is failing ?